# Unconstrained convex quadratic integer programing

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, integer-programming, quadratic-programming

Let $N_i=\{0,1,\dots,\bar{n}_i\}$ and define $N=N_1\times \dots \times N_I$. I have a minimization problem of the form
$$
\min_{n\in N} \sum_i A_i n_i +\sum_i \sum_{j\neq i} B_{ij} (n_i-n_j)^2
$$
where $A_i\geq 0$ and $B_{ij}\geq 0$ for all $i,j$. This problem can be written as a convex quadratic integer program.

What are the standard algorithms to solve these problems numerically? Are they guaranteed to find a global solution? How fast are they?

Comment: This seems like a misnomer to me.  According to Boyd and Vandenberghe, a Convex Optimization problem is an optimization problem whose domain is a convex set.  But an integer programming problem is one where the solutions must be integers.  The set of integers is not convex.

Comment: Yes, I know that using the word "convex" here is a bit tricky but several people in the literature use convex in this way for integer programs.

Comment: Typically, a mixed integer nonlinear programming problem (MINLP) whose continuous relaxation is convex is referred to as a "Convex MINLP"  This is terminology that's been around for at least 25 years...

Comment: Your terminology is fine. You would think it might be possible to exploit the fact that it is unconstrained (that is, beyond the integrality constraints), but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you'd use a branch and bound algorithm to solve this problem and obtain a globally optimal solution if the problem isn't unbounded.  This does require worst-case exponential time.

Several commercial LP/QP packages have support for solving these MIQP problems.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that simpler algorithms might work given the nice properties of the problem but maybe that's not the case.